# How to display a part of a big image?

Tags: flutter

I got an image that is landscape and want to use it on my phone (portrait).

I don't want to resize my image. I just want to use what I need based on my screen size and start from the middle of it. And if I want to start from the left, what would be the solution?

I am not sure I am clear, so I created a basic image to explain what I meant.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image:
                const AssetImage("assets/images/login_960x540.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            // colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            // Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: if you want to start from the left, just draw the image at the 0,0 position, if you want to have a different position, just use a negative X value for the image position, or do you want to change the image?

Comment: @Alexanus, based on my 'UPDATE' section, How would you move the image? I used a stack to have my background image and then I put other things on top. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David You can use **FittedBox** and **Alignment** for positioning background image, for example:

```dart
 Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    child: FittedBox(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, //Positioned in start
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      child: Image.asset('assets/image.png'), //If image 100x300, you will see just 100x100
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I based my solution on the alignment that you suggested. Perfect!